# How do I compare the number of lines of code in one version of a project to another?

Tags: svn, diff

More specifically, I'm looking for how to count the number of lines in all files within a directory recursively through all directories. I can simply repeat on each the two different versions of the project to get a comparison figure.

Alternatively, since subversion has a fairly robust diff functionality, is it possible to mutate a diff between the two versions to obtain an absolute difference of lines of code?

Either solution would help me out greatly.

Comment: please specify platform(s) & language(s) you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your platform, but if it happens to be *nix (including cygwin under windows), you could try [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/).  I use it quite a bit for a number of different languages and am very happy with it.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some fantastic tools for counting lines of code as it is a [valuable metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code). They include options like ignoring whitespace and comments.

Just do a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&num=100&q=line+count&btnG=Search) for a line counter specific to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in .NET/Java, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx)/[XDepend](http://www.xdepend.com/) support this.

Comment: Surely these work on the assembly/JAR and don't actually give you "lines of code" from the point of view of the 'source'.  Since the original questioner wanted the results out of subversion, the overhead of building the code may be too much.

Answer (score 0):

I use [LocMetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/) on Windows. Free, and simple "unzip" deployment.